# How to handle HTML5 Web Notifications with a Cocoa WebView?

Tags: cocoa, webkit, nsusernotification

I use a Cocoa WebView to display a website which sends HTML5 Web Notifications. When browsing this page using Safari, I receive User Notifications directly in the Notification Center of Mac OS X Mountain Lion.

How I can achieve the same behavior by implementing my own WebView ? I didn't see any delegate methods related to this feature.

**Edit:** If this can help someone:

https://github.com/jnordberg/irccloudapp/blob/master/NotificationProvider.m

Thanks to Johan Nordberg for sharing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public API for web notifications in WebKit on OS X at this time. You should file an [enhancement request with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com/) requesting that the functionality be exposed. However, since WebKit is open source you can easily find the [private interface on WebView](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebKit/mac/WebView/WebViewPrivate.h?rev=140260#L721) that relates to displaying web notifications. As with all private interfaces, it's subject to change without notice and may not be used within an application in the App Store.

Comment: Or you can implement it in objc and bind it in underlaying javascript environment.